# How to create a Makefile.txt for React app?

Tags: reactjs, makefile

I am working on a take home project for a job interview where I have been tasked to create a react application with frontend and backend tests. They have instructed me that they will execute my code using "the make targets specified in Makefile(which they have provided. see later)". I have completed the application and test cases, however I am quite lost on this last step.

I understand that a makefile is used to execute essentially a script, but unsure of how to tell it to set up the application environment.

Here is a copy of the Makefile.txt

```
.PHONY: $(MAKECMDGOALS)

# `make setup` will be used after cloning or downloading to fulfill
# dependencies, and setup the the project in an initial state.
# This is where you might download rubygems, node_modules, packages,
# compile code, build container images, initialize a database,
# anything else that needs to happen before your server is started
# for the first time
setup:

# `make server` will be used after `make setup` in order to start
# an http server process that listens on any unreserved port
#   of your choice (e.g. 8080). 
server:

# `make test` will be used after `make setup` in order to run
# your test suite.
test:
```

Any help, understanding or clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is about scripts that you have in `package.json` file - [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts), they probably want to have something like `make setup` script and all others that will run specific functionality for example if they type `make test` in terminal it will start running tests like `npm test`